# How to implement custom WSDL extensions?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

Let’s assume I have a XML element in WSDL (1.1) file that is not from WSDL specification (new WSDL extension). At deploy time (Java) I would like to read this element and do something (e.g. call an EJB).

Any ideas how to implement this? Which server would you choose? Glassfish? Tomcat? Axis?

Help would be greatly appreciated ;)

Thank you!